# App Store "Get" button text in all languages

Tags: ios, app-store

Does anybody know if there is a way (parse or fetch) to get text of "Get" button in all languages supported in app store?
[image]

Comment: your question is good, but we can't handle it

Answer (score 0):

This is handle by `Localization`. If you want to learn then here is the link of [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/) and [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)

Hope this will help.:)

Comment: Isn't it something controlled by App Store itself? I haven't found the answer in the links you've provided.

Comment: This links are basic about localization. it's wide concept. google it about this. you can make your app with multiple language support.

Comment: Do you just want to get all translations of "Get" on the App Store or do you want to control what's shown within the App Store app? Last option is definitely not possible.

Comment: I just want to get all translations of "Get" on the App Store.